# Make an HTTP request with body names set in @JsonProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, retrofit2

I have a Spring Boot application with Jackson to process JSON, and I am using Retrofit2 to make HTTP requests. I would like to send body parameters with the name set in the `@JsonProperty` annotation:

```
public class OAuthTokenRequest {

  @JsonProperty("oauth_consumer_key")
  private String consumerKey;

  @JsonProperty("oauth_nonce")
  private String nonce;

  @JsonProperty("oauth_timestamp")
  private Long timestamp;

  ...
}
```

And this would be the request:

```
@POST("/oauth-service/oauth/request_token")
Call<ResponseBody> getOauthToken(@Body OAuthTokenRequest request);
```

In this code fragment, I would like to send the parameters as named in the annotations (`oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_nonce`, `oauth_timestamp`, etc.). However, the parameters are being sent like this:
[image: Request parameters]

Comment: The above code would be sending the paramaters as named in the annotations. Is the above code not working that way ?

Comment: It's not working, I have edited the question to add an image of how the request parameters are being sent

Answer (score 0):

Above your class add below annotaion

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)

public class OAuthTokenRequest {

  @JsonProperty("oauth_consumer_key")
  private String consumerKey;

  @JsonProperty("oauth_nonce")
  private String nonce;

  @JsonProperty("oauth_timestamp")
  private Long timestamp;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this but I am getting the same result

Comment: what about removing @JsonProperty?